# Using Vue.js in a WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

I implemented a simple contact form with Recaptcha in Vue.js, see [live demo](https://test.developernote.com/JsLib/contact-form/) and the [source code](https://github.com/elephantbug/JsLib/tree/master/contact-form).

What is the right way to add this form on a WordPress page? I have not worked with WordPress, so it is not clear where to include the script and where to put HTML and PHP. Developing a plugin is probably too complicated, is it possible to have the contact form that can be added to a WordPress page with couple lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution with webpack:

1. create vue component which you want to include
2. create some index.js or index.ts file that you can include in webpack entry
3. add component in wordpress by some hook. e.g add_menu_page

   ```
       add_action( 'admin_menu',array($this, 'register_form_menu_page'));
       function register_form_menu_page(){
           add_menu_page(  
               __( 'captcha form', 'theme' ),
               __( 'captcha form', 'theme' ),
               'edit_posts',
               'captchaform',
               array($this, 'init_menu_form'),
               'dashicons-schedule',
               6
           ); 
       }
   ```

   `function init_menu_form() { ?>
          <div>
              <captcha-form class="app-vue"></captcha-form>
           </div>
       <?php }`
4. in javascript index file include vue, vue component, and create vue instance

   `

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue';
   import CaptchaForm from "./components/CaptchaForm.vue";
   Vue.component('CaptchaForm', CaptchaForm);

   var apps = document.getElementsByClassName('app-vue');
   for (let i = 0; i < apps.length; i++) {
       let element = apps[i];
       let id = 'app-vue-' + i;
       element.setAttribute('id', id);
       new Vue({
           el: '#' + id,
       });
   }
   export default apps;
   ```
5. run webpack